# Is it possible to mine 26 diamonds in 40 minutes or less?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend told me he can mine 26 diamonds in 40 minutes. I think it's kind of impossible after a few hours of calculation. But is there any chance for my friend to do that?

Edit: the Minecraft version is 1.17, and after told him my point, he said he use x-ray glitch. Can it help him find diamonds that fast?

Comment: This depends entirely on where the diamonds actually generate.

Comment: Really, if you know exactly where they are or are very lucky, its entirely possible. Not like there is a skill to mining diamonds faster than someone else. You just need to actually find them.

Comment: I mean, you could in theory first find diamonds but not mine them, and once you find 26, backtrack and mine them all within the time, providing they are close enough that travel time won't exceed the time limit.

Comment: On the same train of thought as @TimmyJim, you could also just silk touch the the diamond ores and mine well over a hundred in 26 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X-ray is not a glitch, rather a mod (and resource pack) that allows player to see through (almost) everything to find ores, chests, etc.

You'll see through blocks like this (taken from [CurseForge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/xray-1-13-rift-modloader)'s webpage):

[image: Screenshot of X-ray]

So yes, you can easily get 26 diamonds in 40 minutes if you used X-ray. I would even say that that's low amount of diamonds if your friend used X-ray.

Comment: No, my friend told me the world looks like this: [link](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/X-ray_glitches?file=X-Ray_View_Night_Vision.png) in that glitch. So is it possible for my friend to find 24 diamonds in 40 min if he using this glitch?

Comment: or without using any mod, glitch, hack. Is it still possible ?

Comment: @BaoDinh Well then that would depends on where the diamonds got generated. Still, if any player that has a tremendous luck, yes, it's possible.

Comment: 9minecraft is known for reposting mods without the author's permission. I submitted an edit to change it to another mod on CurseForge.

Comment: @MrParrot Approved it, thanks for that information!

Comment: The X-ray glitch doesn't allow you to see ores as they are all culled (combined with the stone for performance reasons).

However, you can use it to see ores if they are directly visible from caves revealed by this method.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is also doable in vanilla, particularly if you had a Fortune III pickaxe.  Diamond ore generates in blobs of up to 5 blocks (average 2.5), and Fortune III gives you a max of 4 diamonds per block (average 2.2).  So if you were lucky with the drops you could get 26 diamonds from only two blobs.  That's easily findable in 40 minutes of caving, and definitely possible mining.  On average you'd need 5 blobs.  Possible in 40 minutes caving, but unlikely mining.

Answer (score 2):

As of the 1.18 update, it is very doable with Fortune III, but otherwise, possible, but you have to get lucky (with no glitches). Efficiency allows you to mine more blocks, increasing the odds. Very doable if you have a Efficiency 5 and Fortune 3 pick.

Source: I’ve found the same amount in half the time with Efficiency 5 and Fortune 3.

Comment: Better strip mining then caving now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a swamp area, find a patch of clay, then open the chunk border and go 7 blocks from the middle of the clay patch, you will then find diamonds if you do it right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Woah, that works?  Can you test this in creative?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.17, diamond ore has a very small chance to generate as a large blob, of up to 23 ore.

If your friend was very lucky to have found a large blob and a regular blob he could have found 26 as he claims.

See https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore#Natural_generation